# react router no me funciona, muestra todo en blanco

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

la pagina se queda en blanco cuando carga el navegador,las rutas no acceden , ya he intentado todo y no funciona
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

```
    const Rutas = () => {
      return (
        <div>
            <div className="container">
            <h1>Router</h1>
            </div>
            <Router>
    
            <Route exact path="/" >
                <h2>Home</h2>
                <p>Home page </p>
              </Route>
           
              <Route path="/about">
                <h2>About</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Accusamus id deleniti 
             quas fuga, dolorum odio.</p>
              </Route>
    
              <Route path="/contact">
                <h2>Contact</h2>
              </Route>
    
            </Router>
    
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Rutas
```

Comment: que version del router instalaste? porque si es la 5 te faltan los switch envolviendo a los route

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando Switch así:

```
import React from 'react' import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
```

y `<Switch> </Switch>` dentro de Router `<Router> </Router>` así:

```
   <Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" >
          <h2>Home</h2>
          <p>Home page </p>
       </Route>
           
       <Route path="/about">
          <h2>About</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
       </Route>
    
       <Route path="/contact">
           <h2>Contact</h2>
       </Route>
     </Switch>
    </Router>
```

¡Espero te ayude!

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando la React Router v6 debes utilizar `Routes`. Si es react Router v5 debes utilizar `Switch`

```
import React from 'react' import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const Rutas = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Router</h1>
      </div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <p>Home page </p>
          </Route>

          <Route path="/about">
            <h2>About</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
              Accusamus id deleniti quas fuga, dolorum odio.
            </p>
          </Route>

          <Route path="/contact">
            <h2>Contact</h2>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Rutas;
```